# how to check if apache2 serving static content?

Tags: apache

I have setup Apache2 to serve all content of a folder including it's sub-folder to serve static content e.g. images. How can I verify if it is working?

Just to clarify, Apache2 is setup on a server and yes I can see my pages using browser. What I want to know is how do I know the page is being served as "static" content? it's not if I can see the page or image.. I want to know how the serve is serving the page? make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting to yourself in a web browser. You can just use the 'loopback' address by typing 127.0.0.1 in the address bar. If you have an index page you should see it displayed. If not then you'll have to also request a specific image like 127.0.0.1/image.jpg or if it resides in a sub-directory use 127.0.0.1/subdirectory/image.jpg

Comment: I have added some more clarifications if that helps to answer my question - thanks.

Comment: If you're not using anything to dynamically change the files then they are static. An example of a non-static webpage would be one where the HTML code doesn't exist in a file on the server but is pieced together by the server. If you have a file on your server that contains the full HTML code and apache just serves that to users then that's static content. Images are static content as well because you just access the file on the server without alteration.